# Having trouble with basic if then statement

Tags: shell, shell-script, exit

learning the basics of scripting and I have this line of code:

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ $# -ne 1]  
then
   echo "Please provide one directory to search"
   echo "Example usage: something.sh directory_name"
   exit 1
fi
```

however when I run this I get the error `if: Expression Syntax.` what exactly am I missing here?
also the next if statement gives me the same error as well:(I want it to check if the variable is a directory or not

```
if [ !-d $1 ]
then
   echo "$1: Invalid Directory. Aborting Script."
   exit 1
fi
```

full script in case that helps:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo "Please provide one directory to search"
   echo "Example usage: something directory_name"
   exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d $1 ]
then
   echo "$1: Invalid Directory. Aborting Script."
   exit 1
fi
cd "$1"
read=0
write=0
exe=0
numFiles=0
numDir=0
for filename in *
do
if [ -r filename ]
then
   `expr $read + 1`
fi
if [ -x filename ]
then
   `expr $exe + 1`
fi
if [ -w filename ]
then
   `expr $write + 1`
fi
if [ -f filename ]
then
   `expr $numFiles + 1`
fi
done
for dir in */
do
if [ -r dir ]
then
   `expr $read + 1`
fi
if [ -x dir ]
then
   `expr $exe + 1`
fi
if [ -w dir ]
then
    `expr $write + 1`
fi
if [ -d dir ]
then
   `expr $numDir + 1`
fi
done
total=`expr $numDir + $numFiles`
echo "In the directory $1"
echo "  Number of directories     : $numDir"
echo "  Number of files           : $numFiles"
echo "  Number of readable items  : $read"
echo "  Number of writable        : $write"
echo "  Number of executable items: $exe"
echo "-------------------------------"
echo "Total number of items: $total"
```

UPDATE: Just in case anyone stumbles upon this, I had header comments before the `#!/bin/bash` which was causing the if expression error

Comment: It's also a good practice to quote your variables.`"$1"`

Comment: @taliezin thanks, i put the spaces in but its still giving me the same error, and I put a couple debug statemtns in that arent being read so it definitely lies within tjose lines of code

Comment: Could it have to do with line breaks? Windows to unix mismatches? you can run `dos2unix` on the file if you have to confirm. It would also help if you paste your entire script.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Neither bash nor dash give me that error message (they both complain of a missing `]`). Is it possible you're using csh/tcsh? How are you running this script?

Comment: @derobert im using bourne shell I believe, Ill go ahead and post the full script

Comment: How are you starting this script? Also, `ls -l /bin/sh` and `echo "$SHELL"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few issues. Here is the working version. You need to use $ to denote the value of a variable ( `$filename` instead of `filename` ) and you need to assign the result of an expression to a variable, rather than just invoking the expression ( `read=expr $read + 1` instead of `expr $read + 1` ).

```
 #!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo "Please provide one directory to search"
   echo "Example usage: assignment4.sh directory_name"
   exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d "$1" ]
then
   echo "$1: Invalid Directory. Aborting Script."
   exit 1
fi
cd "$1"
read=0
write=0
exe=0
numFiles=0
numDir=0
for filename in *
do
if [ -r "$filename" ]
then
   read=`expr $read + 1`
fi
if [ -x filename ]
then
   exe=`expr $exe + 1`
fi
if [ -w "$filename" ]
then
   write=`expr $write + 1`
fi
if [ -f "$filename" ]
then
   numFiles=`expr $numFiles + 1`
fi
done
for dir in */
do
if [ -r "$dir" ]
then
   read=`expr $read + 1`
fi
if [ -x "$dir" ]
then
   exe=`expr $exe + 1`
fi
if [ -w "$dir" ]
then
    write=`expr $write + 1`
fi
if [ -d "$dir" ]
then
   numDir=`expr $numDir + 1`
fi
done
total=`expr $numDir + $numFiles`
echo "In the directory $1"
echo "  Number of directories     : $numDir"
echo "  Number of files           : $numFiles"
echo "  Number of readable items  : $read"
echo "  Number of writable        : $write"
echo "  Number of executable items: $exe"
echo "-------------------------------"
echo "Total number of items: $total"
$ ./script.sh
Please provide one directory to search
Example usage: something.sh directory_name

$ ./script.sh /home/username

In the directory /home/username
  Number of directories     : 8
  Number of files           : 104
  Number of readable items  : 120
  Number of writable        : 120
  Number of executable items: 8
-------------------------------
Total number of items: 112
```

Comment: I think  my code is just cursed, made all those corrections and it still gives me that error, but when I run a new .sh file with the exact code it runs perfectly. thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3470987 have you edited the original file in Windows at some point? Sounds like you might have some stray `\r` characters.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is spaces.

This works:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo "One argument needed"
   exit 1
fi
```

Likewise:

```
if [ ! -d $1 ]
```

Comment: thanks, I'm still getting the same error though...put in a couple debug statements after and it wont read them either so the problem definitely lies within those couple lines.